# Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 crashing during initial install if I put a dash in the name

Tags: server, system-installation, 22.04, bug-reporting

I have tried multiple times to install Ubuntu servers 22.04 and 22.04.1 AMD 64bit to have the installation crash. I am installing it onto an ESXi 6.7 server. After multiple configuration changes, I have found including a dash '-' in the computer, name causes this error in both normal server and minimal server installs. Language is set to English and all default ubuntu install settings and ESXi settings. I have also tried to spin up a VM on Proxmox and virtual box and had the same problem.

I have not been able to find where to submit this as a bug as the input field restricts certain characters eg Capitals, a feel either it should restrict dashes or allow them and not crash.

Is this a problem that anyone else is experiencing?
Where can I report this bug to?
Is this a bug?